# How to get comments from multiple post type?

Tags: comments

How can I get comments from multiple post type? I want to display 5 comments from my different post types pages.

```
<?php 

$defaults = array(
    'number' => 5,
    'post_type' => array('post','authors','movies')
);
$comments = get_comments($defaults);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`WP_Comment_Query()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L165) only supports a single post type.

You can adjust it, by using the `comments_clauses` filter.

Try for example:

```
$defaults = array(
    'number'    => 5,
    'post_type' => array( 'post','authors','movies' ),
);
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_121051', 10, 2 );     
$comments = get_comments($defaults)
```

where

```
 /**
  * Support for multiple post types for comments
  *
  * @param array $clauses
  * @param object $wpqc WP_Comment_Query
  * @return array $clauses
  */   
 function wpse_121051( $clauses, $wpqc )
 {
    global $wpdb;

    // Remove the comments_clauses filter, we don't need it anymore. 
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Add the multiple post type support.
    if( isset( $wpqc->query_vars['post_type'][0] ) )
    {

        $join = join( "', '", array_map( 'esc_sql', $wpqc->query_vars['post_type'] ) );

        $from = "$wpdb->posts.post_type = '" . $wpqc->query_vars['post_type'][0] . "'";                         
        $to   = sprintf( "$wpdb->posts.post_type IN ( '%s' ) ", $join );

        $clauses['where'] = str_replace( $from, $to, $clauses['where'] );
    }  

    return $clauses;
 }
```

### The plugin:

As kindly suggested by @kaiser, I made a [small plugin](https://github.com/birgire/wp-comments-from-mulitple-post-types)  to add multiple post types support to `WP_Comment_Query()` and `get_comments()`. Let's hope this missing feature will be supported by the WordPress core in the near future ;-)

Comment: ok great, I just updated the answer that should be more easier to work with.

Comment: Cool thing! Should be a plugin :)

Comment: @kaiser: thanks, ... [here](https://github.com/birgire/wp-comments-from-mulitple-post-types) we go, a tiny plugin with a long name ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone comes across this question, WordPress now accepts an array for the `post_type`parameter for `get_comments()`